# Invoking a pure virtual method within a thread

Tags: c++, c++11, stdthread

I have the requirement of invoking a pure virtual method implementation when spawning a thread from within a base class method as shown below.

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
  private:
    std::thread tr;

  public:
    virtual void baz() = 0;
    void foo() {
      this->tr = std::thread([=] { this->baz(); });
    }

};

class Bar : public Foo {
  public:
    void baz() {
      std::cout << "In baz" << "\n";
    }

};
```

Main class...

```
#include <thread>
#include "test.hpp"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  Bar b;
  b.foo();
}
```

But it fails with the message

> terminate called without an active exception
>
> pure virtual method called

The message "pure virtual method called" appears only in some of the failure messages. What am I doing wrong? Is it something related to Bar or the thread getting improperly destructed?

Comment: Where are you joining on your thread?  What's stopping your main from completing instantly?

Comment: Your program exhibits undefined behavior by way of a data race on `b`, between `baz()` call on the worker thread and `~Bar()` call on the main thread. Most likely, `main` returns and `b` is destroyed before the thread gets to `this->baz()`.

Comment: You do not 'have the requirement of invoking a pure virtual method'. This is the *problem,* not the requirement.

Comment: I suspect this is an example of trying to take a threading idiom from another language and importing it into C++, and things going wrong.

Comment: Right. I am missing a join here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Igor pointed out in his comment, you have a data race. The thread is actually executed after `Bar` gets destroyed (the actual order of execution is not defined, of course, so you may get lucky sometimes). To prevent this, you need to `tr.join();` before `Bar` gets destroyed.

```
class Foo {
    std::thread tr;
protected:
    void join() { tr.join(); }
public:
    virtual ~Foo() = default;  // ~Foo should be virtual or protected, if Foo contains virtual methods
    virtual void baz() = 0;
    void foo() {
        this->tr = std::thread([=] { this->baz(); });
    }
};

class Bar : public Foo {
public:
    ~Bar() { join(); }
    void baz() { std::cout << "In baz" << "\n"; }
};
```

If you want to investigate this more, add some `cout`s in various methods (especially the destructors), and add a `std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::seconds(1))` at various places.

Comment: Note that `join` should be called in `~Bar` and not in `~Foo`. Which make the OP design fragile.

Comment: @Jarod42 I agree, this design is fragile. Manually joining in `~Foo` would not do anything, since this would happen anyway as the thread gets destructed (but that happens after `~Bar` gets destructed). I did not want to elaborate too much on the OPs design, though ...

Comment: @chtz what if to use some conditional? This boils down that we should not allow  objects to be destroyed before thread finishes execution, or thread would address invalid memory ( supposed pure call seem to be implementation specific). Which somehow not an issue with Microsoft compiler apparently, this problem comes up with QtQuick objects on Linux (because they run  Jscript in separate threads), but not on Windows

Comment: @Swift I don't understand your question. I guess there are possibilities to solve the data race using `std::condition_variable`, if that is what you mean (I doubt they will be simpler). I have never worked with `QtQuick` objects, so I have no idea if/how the last part relates to the OP's problem.